# Why (Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) return false when user granted all file access permission (ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS)?

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, storage, android-11

I want to get storage permissions on Android 11 and later
After the user deny permission twice; I enable direct intent to the full storage licensing page with this flag:
Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
The user grants this permission and even the condition:
ٍ Environment.isExternalStorageManager ()
Is also true, but still returns the Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission false.
I do not understand why.
Can anyone guide me?

More description:

When user click to open gallery icon, i request get storage permission runtime and os appear a dialog to get user that choose between grant or deny that permission. in android 10 and lower, if user deny permission, every time user click on open gallery icon again, that dialog too appears again. but in android 11 and on wards, if user deny any runtime permission twice, os do not let to appear permission dialog anymore. in this case i start an intent with (Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION) action flag to get manually this permission

Comment: `After the user rejects the license twice;` ?? What are you or the user doing?

Comment: My app is messenger and need to access to user storage to send media

Comment: Ok. But you still did not tell what you are doing.

Comment: This is what I want.
Obtain permission to access storage run time including read and write external storage for send media to another in app in android 11 onwards

Comment: `After the user deny permission twice;` Unclear what is happening. And which permission? Cant you just write in your post what is happening? I have no idea what you do.

Comment: When user click to open gallery icon, i request get storage permission runtime and os appear a dialog to get user that choose between grant or deny that permission. in android 10 and lower, if user deny permission, every time user click on open gallery icon again, that dialog too appears again. but in android 11 and on wards, if user deny any runtime permission twice, os do not let to appear permission dialog anymore. in this case i start an intent with (Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION) action flag to get manually this permission

Comment: but when user granted (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) manually and come back to app, (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission is still return false

Comment: Please put all relevant info in your post. Not in comments. Write a decent post to begin with. We want to be able to follow what you do from the first line of your post. See my first comment.